# How do I get each of the entries from Guava MultiMap and their corresponding values associated with it?

Tags: java, csv, guava, multimap

I am reading from a huge csv file which contains duplicate entries. I was able to read the whole csv file into a `Multimap`. I am also able to obtain the keyset with duplicate values and write them to a file. I want to get the value associated with each of the keys and write it to a file but unable to do so. I cant seem to find any of the options that might help me. I tried using `entries()` method which according to [the doc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

> Returns a view collection of all key-value pairs contained in this multimap, as `Map.Entry` instances

but I am unable to get anything from it.

I am using `ArrayListMultiMap` implementation of `MultiMap`. Reason for using `ArrayList` is that later I need to perform a search operation which is quicker in an `ArrayList`.

I have pstored the keyset as a `MultiSet` which is why I am able to get all the duplicate keys.

Value of each of the keys is an object which I want to be written to a file corresponding to that read key.

Comment: Can you [edit] this to make it more clear: 1. What you've done (preferably with code) 2. What you're trying to do (preferably with an example). See: [mcve]

Comment: So you've got effectively got a `Multimap<FileName, ContentsToGoInFile>` and you want all the values for a given key so you can put them in a single file?

Comment: @Edd It is more like Multimap<String, SomeClassObject>. I have been able to get all the Strings (including the duplicate ones) as a keyset, but now want to get the associated SomeClassObject with each key, preferably at the same time so that I can write them to a file as a record.

Answer (score 2):

If you want each key and each value associated with that key, instead of each key-value pair, then you can do that with

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<SomeClassObject>> entry : multimap.asMap().entrySet()) {
   String key = entry.getKey();
   Collection<SomeClassObject> valuesForKey = entry.getValue();
   // do whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It is not solving my problem. Here is what I am thinking and quite sure that I am wrong as I have been doing this for 3 hours without progress. There are only say 10 unique keys. Each of those keys has 1000 values associated with it. Now since eventually I want to do a comparison between two files that contain this same data, I plan on making one List each of values alongwith its key. So I will end up with a big collection of 10 bis lists. I would then like to compare both of them and then proceed on further. This is my use case. Do you think I am thinking correctly?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with that.  I don't understand where your problem is.

Comment: I am unable to get a list of those 1000 values for each of those unique keys. Following your example, after valuesForKey has been entirely populated, it will again get added as an element to a higher super list? What kind of collection do I choose to acheive that? If I try doing something with ArrayList, I get "Out of Memory" error.

Comment: "it will again get added as an element to a higher super list?" what?  Is that part of your approach, or something you think is required for Multimap?  (It isn't.)  Show us the code that's giving you errors.

Comment: My problem right now is that if I use your code, it is picking up only one "entry" and their corresponding values. So if I have a total of 10,000 records, I am only getting 2000 associated with only one key. If I use an Iterator in a while loop and go over the keyset with it, it just gets stuck.

Comment: I understand your earlier comment when you highlighted about "higher list". Each entry of a multimap will already be correspondig to some list, ex: entry A to [1,2, 3], B to [2,3, 5] etc. So in your example code, valuesForKey is that higher list which I was thinking of.. correct? Also, when I put that code in a while loop with condition iterator.hasNext, then it is going into an infinite loop I think. Also, what will be a proper way to iterate over that Collection<SomeClassObject> valuesForKey so that I can check what is going in it. Thank you.

Comment: What iterator?  There's no iterator or `while` loop you're dealing with here; just use the `for` loop I gave you.  `valuesForKey` will be only the values for that one key, yes.  Iterate over `valuesForKey` just like any other collection, with a normal `for` loop.

Comment: @user3044240 Have you noted that Louis is calling `.entrySet()` on [`multimap.asMap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap()), so he is iterating over a `Set<Entry<String, Collection<SomeClassObject>>>`, not a `Set<Entry<String, SomeClassObject>>`, as you would get from `multimap.entries()`.

Comment: @Edd I understand that but the thing right now is that if I iterate over valuesForKey then it is only showing entries for one key only. If I am expecting 10,000 entries in total from all the keys, then instead I am only getting 2000, which are associated with one key. It is not that it has picking up the first key or last, it is just a randomly selected key. What can be wrong?

Comment: I just debugged and it does read through each value in keyset but it only keeps the last key and displays values asociated with it. I was wrong to say that it is picking up a random key, instead it is going through each entry but removing them as it goes through, therefore just keeping the last one. Which collection will make it keep all the entries and not just the last one?

Comment: Show us your code that is doing that.  It is a bug in your code, not Guavas.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, there are two ways to think about Multimaps. One is as a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`, and the other is as a `Map<K, V>`, where the keys do not have to be unique. In [the documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap), Google stresses that the latter approach is preferred, although if you do `multimap.asMap().entries()` (N.B. Not just `multimap.entries()`), as Louis suggested, you will have entries like the former version.

For your particular problem, I'm not sure why you can't do something like the following:

```
for (String key : multimap.keySet()) {
    Collection<SomeClassObject> values = multimap.get(key);
    //Do whatever with all the values for Key key...
}
```

Comment: If I try to do that then it is not giving me values of "each" key like it is being mentioned. It is only picking up one "key" and printing it all its values. It doesn't start in sequence and just picks up a random value. If all keys in keyset are unique, which I know for sure, then why does it pick up only one key?

Comment: I just debugged and it does read through each value in keyset but it only keeps the last key and displays values asociated with it. I was wrong to say that it is picking up a random key, instead it is going through each entry but removing them as it goes through, therefore just keeping the last one. Which collection will make it keep all the entries and not just the last one?

Comment: After reading through each entry, I added that list to another ArrayList of Collection<SomeClassObject> and then I am able to get each key and all its associated values.